# QNetworkReply does not get any headers

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I'm coding an application to get information of a device on which I have to send a PUT request like this:

```
connect(&netman,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,
    SLOT(reqFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
QByteArray data("0ABF0A25");
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://192.168.1.100:8088"));
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader,data.length());
QNetworkReply rep =netman.put(req,data);
connect(rep, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this,
    SLOT(errorSlot(QNetworkReply::NetworkError))):
```

I know the device is working because it starts its process and if I put a sniffer between my PC and the device and I see the response .

485454502F312E3020323030204F4B200D0A
or in plain text 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK \r\n'

but when the `slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* rep)` slot is executed I get no data, no headers and no attributes, and error code 2 (connection closed).

If i execute:

```
QVariant attr = rep->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
```

I get and invalid variant object, same for the headers.

How can I get the raw packets of the response? That would be handy for this case.

I also noticed on my sniffer that the connection repeats three times, and sends the request all these times for one only put request; Could that be an issue with the library?

Comment: You mean you get QMetaType::Unknown? Also, which qt version are you using? Btw, could you please provide a self-contained example? Check sscce.org for details.

Comment: Yes that's the QVariant I get, I'm using Qt 5.1.1. ... there is no much about the code, except that a get request works OK, but the put request behave the way I described, I'm guessing there is an issue with the device,I can do little about that, if I could get the raw data as using QTcpSocket that would be nice

Comment: Have you checked the error signals just in case, or the error(String) in general? Also, please provide some code, and hardware reference, etc. Otherwise, it is a bit more difficult to help.

Comment: Yes the error signal and errorString from QNetworkReply also says connection closed (error code 2). I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 on VirtualBox, I'll edit the question to add the basic code, tnxs!

Comment: QNetworkReply from the initial code block should be QNetworkRequest? Did you try with a proper URL, i.e. http://192.168.1.100?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did mistype the class, and yes the URL is ok, as the device send a packet containing HTTP/1.0 200 OK, but QNAM and/or QNetworkReply does not gets it

Answer (score 0):

I had to sub-class the QNetworkAccessManager class to implement my custom put method using QTCpSocket in order the get an appropriate response, I cannot create a QNetworkReply and set values to the attributes so a little workaround was applied :P
And of course the readyRead signal of QTcpSocket is connected to the socketRead slot of this class, also the error signals are connected to other slots

.h

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class MyNetworkAccessManager : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyNetworkAccessManager(QObject *parent = 0);   
    virtual void myPut(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QByteArray &data);

signals:
    void dataReceived(QNetworkReply*,const QByteArray data);

public slots:
    void socketRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket socket;
};
```

.cpp

```
void MyNetworkAccessManager::MyNetworkAccessManager(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QByteArray &data)
{
    QUrl url = request.url();
    QString host = url.host();
    int len = data.length();
    int port = url.port();
    QString path = url.path();

    QByteArray reqba = QString("PUT %1 HTTP/1.1\r\n\
Content-Type: application/xml\r\n\
Content-Length: %2\r\n\
User-Agent: MyFooAgent/0.1\r\n\
Host: %3:%4\r\n\r\n").arg(path).arg(len).arg(host).arg(port).toUtf8();


    socket.connectToHost(host, port, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    socket.waitForConnected();  
    socket.write(reqba + data);

}

void MyNetworkAccessManager::socketRead()
{
    QByteArray data = socket.readAll();
    socket.close();
    int code = 0;
    if(data.contains("200 OK"))
        code = 200;
    else if(data.contains("404 Not Found"))
        code = 404;
    //else if ..... foo
    emit dataReceived(data,code);
}
```